# C# HtmlElement Freeze on x64

Tags: c#

When I access a HtmlElement from a webbrowser form in a non sta thread on vista x64. The application slows down tremendously, starts using 50+ cpu and starts to freeze. Why does it only do this on x64, im using the .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: Show us the code you're using.